# Is spacetime emergent?

Tags: spacetime, models

Does space exist independently from its content, or is it in some way "created" by it?

What I'm interested about is this question: Say we copied the standard model and duplicated its particles, fields, everything, but left it "independent", that is, particles from the duplicated models do not have masses, charges, etc. but masses "2", charges "2", etc., where for instance charges "2" do not directly interact with regular charges. We also create a bit of matter from the duplicated model to go with it.

Would it make sense for particles from the two models to be present in the same space? Or would the fact that they have two different kinds of masses automatically imply that their spaces "desync" and basically become two independent spaces?

Both cases make sense to me in some way. The first one would imply that the two models still indirectly interact through gravitation, but perhaps this means that they aren't truly independent and that the fields still interact in some way, contradicting the premise of the second model and *forcing* us to specify that they are in a different space? And wouldn't the second imply that space is emergent? The two models not interacting in any way would be what causes a second, independent space to "appear".

I'm asking this for scifi reasons, but the underlying question about whether or not space is emergent seems like a prerequisite to answer the "toy model" question, which is why I asked this stack.

(I think the "model" tag is right for this, I did read the tag wiki. I couldn't think of other relevent tags to add.)

Comment: What do you mean by "exist"?

Comment: I cannot define existence, I mean existence as a physical thing, whether or not it contains anything, and not just an abstract idea. Not in the way numbers exists, but the way that, say, an object that will not ever interact with or be witnessed by anything sentient still "exists".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a general and agreed theory of [mass generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_generation), we don’t know whether a second form of inertial mass is possible at the fundamental particle level. And without a general and agreed theory of [quantum gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gravity) we don’t know how a second form of inertial mass at the fundamental particle level would translate into gravitational mass at a macroscopic level. In our current state of knowledge, we don’t even know for sure (i.e from experimental observation) how the [gravitational interaction of antimatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_interaction_of_antimatter) works.

So you are free to speculate. If your speculations can be backed up with experimental evidence (which is the difficult bit) then there is a Nobel prize with your name on it.

Comment: I see, would it be appropriate to ask about what a second form of inertial mass would imply in *some* proposed (but not generally agreed on) theories or would that imply tedious calculations (to ultimately achieve nothing in particular)?

Answer (score 0):

According to some prominent researchers in emergent gravity (such as Mark Van Raamsdonk) spacetime is built up of quantum entanglement.

> This implies that quantum entanglement is the fundamental property
> that gives rise to spacetime.

from : *Mark Van Raamsdonk Building up spacetime with quantum entanglement*

> "it is fascinating that the possible unity of gravitational theories
> as suggested by string theory leaves open the possibility  such an
> exact and universal entanglement-gravity duality"..

from : *Building up spacetime with quantum entanglement II: It from BC-bit Mark Van Raamsdonk*

Use quantum information — in particular, the amount of entanglement between different parts of the state, as measured by the mutual information — to define a “distance” between them.
Parts that are highly entangled are considered to be nearby, while unentangled parts are far away.

*entanglement is all about information*

as quantum information is emergent from degree of freedom following this definition of information :

"information as it is a quantum state change is due to the modification of one degree of freedom from the considered quantum system."

*it is all about Degree of Freedom*

we start from an assumption that the degrees of freedom corresponding to any particular region of space are described by a finite-dimensional Hilbert space. In some sense this is natural, as it follows from the Bekenstein bound (on the total entropy that can fit in a region) or the holographic principle (which limits degrees of freedom by the area of the boundary of their region). But on the other hand, it’s completely contrary to what we’re used to thinking about from quantum field theory, which generally assumes that the number of degrees of freedom in any region of space is infinitely big, corresponding to an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.